# Error in spliiting array and removing comma - javascript/VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Console Error:
Unhandled error during execution of mounted hook
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')

It seems to work up until it comes across a group that has no data for continent.

This looks like the issue to me but I'm not sure how to solve it.

Also I would like if possible to remove duplicates and the end comma for all fileds in the JSO. Is there a better way to do this as one function?

Any help is greatly appreciated

```
     JSON
      "response": [
{ 
"group": { 
"continent": "ASIA,EUROPE,ASIA,EUROPE,ASIA,ASIA,EUROPE,EUROPE,ASIA,AUSTRALASIA,AUSTRALASIA,EUROPE,",
"location": "AS,AS,AS,AS,EU,AF,EU,AF,AU,AU,AU,AU,", 
}, 
},
{ 
"group": {
"continent": "ASIA,EUROPE,AFRICA,EUROPE,ASIA,AFRICA,EUROPE,",
"location": "AS,AS,AS,AU,AU,", 
}, 
},
{ 
"group": {
"continent": "ASIA,",
}, 
},
{ 
"group": {
"continent": "EUROPE,",
}, 
},
{ 
"group": {
"continent": "ASIA,EUROPE,",
"location": "AU,AU,"
}, 
},
 ....
]
 
methods: {
 removeDuplicates() {
      const  uniques = [];
      this.response.group.continent.split(",").forEach((l) => {
        if ( uniques.indexOf(l) == -1 && l !== "") {
           uniques.push(l);
        }
      });
      console.log(" uniques : " +  uniques);
      this.continent =  uniques.join(", ");
    },
}

mounted() {    
    this.removeDuplicates();
  }
```

Comment: Can you share a code snippet in the form of a [mcve]? This question doesn't really have anything to do with Vue actually, it's just processing data. Also your JSON is syntactically invalid: is `response` an array of objects or an object?

Comment: Im not sure what else I can add. The JSON is valid in reality but its about 10,000 lines long. I think what I need is how to say 'if the continent is not there, just move to the next one. I have tried a few ways that I hoped would work but they don't seem to unfortunately.

Comment: You can share a _minimal_ example: we are not asking you to share the entire JSON.

Comment: I have added more of the JSON. Hopefully this will be enough. You will see some of the time 'location' is missing in the JSON group data. I think this is why it is failing. Thank again @Terry

Answer (score 1):

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')

This means that `this.response.group.continent` is undefined

Analyzing your data, you should access the same with `this.response[0].group.continent`

Comment: Thank you. I tried to add this.response[0].group.continent but it didnt seem to make a difference.

Comment: @user13928344 Post the full response in a fiddle so that I can look into the exact issue

Comment: @ Nitheesh. Thanks for your offer of help. The files are too large to display I will close this question and try and take time to construct a smaller example which can be shared. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The error message suggests that `this.response.group` is not a string, and by looking at your data, `this.response` is an **array of objects**. Therefore you will need to iterate through in order to access the `group` property of each object in the array. Using `Array.forEach` should do the job with little modification to your logic:

```
const uniques = [];
this.response.forEach(({ group }) => {
  group.continent.split(",").forEach((l) => {
    if ( uniques.indexOf(l) == -1 && l !== "") {
        uniques.push(l);
    }
  });
});
```

See a working example below (it's not a VueJS app, but contains the same logic as proof-of-concept):

```js
const response = [{
    "group": {
      "continent": "ASIA,EUROPE,ASIA,EUROPE,ASIA,ASIA,EUROPE,EUROPE,ASIA,AUSTRALASIA,AUSTRALASIA,EUROPE,",
      "location": "AS,AS,AS,AS,EU,AF,EU,AF,AU,AU,AU,AU,",
    },
  },
  {
    "group": {
      "continent": "ASIA,EUROPE,AFRICA,EUROPE,ASIA,AFRICA,EUROPE,",
      "location": "AS,AS,AS,AU,AU,",
    },
  },
  {
    "group": {
      "continent": "ASIA,",
    },
  },
  {
    "group": {
      "continent": "EUROPE,",
    },
  },
  {
    "group": {
      "continent": "ASIA,EUROPE,",
      "location": "AU,AU,"
    },
  },
];

const uniques = [];
response.forEach(({
  group
}) => {
  group.continent.split(",").forEach((l) => {
    if (uniques.indexOf(l) == -1 && l !== "") {
      uniques.push(l);
    }
  });
});

console.log("Uniques: " + uniques);
const continent = uniques.join(", ");
console.log(continent);
```

### Even better: use `Set()` + `Array.prototype.flatMap()`

A better way is simply to take advantage of ES6 features like [`Set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), which stores a list of unique entries. Then it is just a matter of using [`Array.prototype.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) + `Array.prototype.filter` (to remove empty entries) and passing the flattened array of continents into the set:

```
const continents = response.flatMap(({ group }) => group.continent.split(',')).filter(v => !!v);
const uniques = Array.from(new Set(continents));
```

See example below:

```js
const response = [{
    "group": {
      "continent": "ASIA,EUROPE,ASIA,EUROPE,ASIA,ASIA,EUROPE,EUROPE,ASIA,AUSTRALASIA,AUSTRALASIA,EUROPE,",
      "location": "AS,AS,AS,AS,EU,AF,EU,AF,AU,AU,AU,AU,",
    },
  },
  {
    "group": {
      "continent": "ASIA,EUROPE,AFRICA,EUROPE,ASIA,AFRICA,EUROPE,",
      "location": "AS,AS,AS,AU,AU,",
    },
  },
  {
    "group": {
      "continent": "ASIA,",
    },
  },
  {
    "group": {
      "continent": "EUROPE,",
    },
  },
  {
    "group": {
      "continent": "ASIA,EUROPE,",
      "location": "AU,AU,"
    },
  },
];

const continents = response.flatMap(({ group }) => group.continent.split(',')).filter(v => !!v);
const uniques = Array.from(new Set(continents));


console.log("Uniques: " + uniques);
const continent = uniques.join(", ");
console.log(continent);
```

Comment: This looks great @Terry. Thank you! I cant quite get it to work on my page for some reason so Im going to step away until tomorrow to see if I can work it out better then. Thanks again